# Algebraic interpretation of a given graph

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory

Consider the following document:

http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/9405/1/Bloomfield_Oct.pdf

I would like to get feedback from you regarding Figure 1 on page 17, which is reproduced below:

[image]

Could you tell me the details of the structure being represented there? It seems like a homomorphism between rings, but, any specifics? What does each graph stand for? And the connecting lines?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do we need to read all the preceding 17 pages? or can you distill down what is necessary and add it to your question?  It may also help to extract the image and link just the image (with relevant text).  Otherwise, it seems like a lot to ask to have people download a .pdf (at least 17 pages) and sift through it to try to understand your question...

Comment: I just wanted to copy the image, but I was not able to do it technically. The image, the legend and the reference thereof just suffice. No need to go through the whole paper.

Comment: It claims to illustrate satisfying condition 2 to some lemma/proposition/theorem.  However, I cannot understand what proposition 2 is saying (it is apparently very imprecise).

Comment: Condition 1 states that the actual model
is also element of the potential model. But further conditions are necessary
if we want it to become an actual model of T BL. Condition 2 expresses the
fundamental principle of T BL. Namely, that utterances of speakers within
the same group of speakers are more alike than utterances of speakers from
different groups. In this way, it is always possible to distinguish one language
from another. C

Comment: I'd look around on the website to see if I could find the author's email address and ask them.  Something is certainly not clear if you understand what the statement says but do not understand the picture (since the picture is supposed to make the statement clearer).

Comment: I undertand what the statement says and what the graph is supposed to represent under those circumstances. BUT that is not the issuu. I am asking about something very different, namely, what is the mathematical description of the image.

Comment: Unfortunately, the mathematical description of an image is 'whatever the mathematician meant when they drew it'... In other words, unless there is a universally agreed on visual language or standard, it could mean anything. Certainly it looks like two (sub?)graphs connected by edges, but beyond that it's hard to say.

Comment: G1 and G2 are meant to ge Rings, I believe. If so, is there anything that can be drawn from it?

Comment: Really? On page 13, the paper says : "G is a set of groups of speakers". A set of 'groups' is not necessarily a Ring, and it's not even clear if the author means a Group (a set with a binary operation, etc) and not just the colloquial meaning of a synonym of Set. Is it at all possible that a lot of this 'maths' is just meant to look like maths? That's harsh, but none of the terminology is well defined.

Comment: Well, the authors quoted there are well-known epistemologists, with metatheoretic work on physics and so on......Just google Sneed, Moulines, etc.

Comment: Here's my take, without reading the entire paper: $G_1$ and $G_2$ are graphs representing the groups of speakers. The vertices seem to represent the speakers, and edges represent similarity between the speakers (the $\approx$ relation). So the figure is intended to show that within each group, speakers tend to be more similar, and between the two groups, speakers tend to be less similar (since there are more edges within $G_1$ and $G_2$ than there are between them).

Comment: Ok, this is becoming an extended discussion again, but I don't see what their renown in their *own* field has to do with their ability to do Mathematics. It's entirely possible - even quite frequent - for researchers in one field to misapply or misuse techniques from another. I'm not saying their results are wrong, just that their notation is unclear.

Comment: @JavierArias, even if they are well known that doesn't imply that they will necessarily use "well-defined" terminology.  Plus, the author of the paper seems to be neither of those you mention.

Comment: Could any of those two graphs, G1 or G2, be seen as a lattice with a maximal ideal?

Comment: @JavierArias Can you explain why you think rings and ideals are involved at all? Doing a search in the paper doesn't pull up either word.

Comment: Those words do not come up in the article, you are right. But lattice representation of languag estructures is partof the background and since ideas and filters are usually defined in lattices....I wondered...